# Changing attachment urls?

Tags: attachments, redirect, urls

How can I change the format of attachment page urls from `/[post-url]/[attachment-name]/` to `/media/[attachment-name]/`? I understand that I can override the output of [`get_attachment_link`](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/branches/3.0/wp-includes/link-template.php#L298) via the `attachment_link` filter, but I guess I need to change the redirect structure so WordPress knows how to handle these urls?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do the following:

```
/* add new rewrite rule */
function attachment_rewrite( $wp_rewrite ) {
    $rule = array(
        'media/(.+)' => 'index.php?attachment=' . $wp_rewrite->preg_index(1)
    );

    $wp_rewrite->rules = $rule + $wp_rewrite->rules;
}
add_filter( 'generate_rewrite_rules', 'attachment_rewrite' );

/* redirect standard wordpress attachments urls to new format */
function redirect_old_attachment() {
    global $wp;

    if( !preg_match( '/^media\/(.*)/', $wp->request ) && isset( $wp->query_vars['attachment'] ) ) {
        wp_redirect( site_url( '/media/' . $wp->query_vars['attachment'] ) , 301 );
    }
}
add_filter( 'template_redirect', 'redirect_old_attachment' );
```

Comment: where do we add the above code, do we add it in functions.php or rewrite.php or links-template.php

Comment: add it to your theme functions.php file

Comment: Where can I find / update the `'index.php?attachment='` handler? I want to use my own handler to resolve files, filter only for a specific user(s) & etc