# Proper way to hook wp_get_attachment_url

Tags: plugin-development, uploads

I am trying to hook `wp_get_attachment_url()` with my custom implementation. I am trying to get my post images and any other static data from the Amazon S3 and I was wondering if I can configure the URL with my Amazon bucket URL.

This is what I was trying to do

```
add_filter('wp_get_attachment_url', 'custom_get_attachment_url', 1, 1);

function clrs_get_attachment_url($post_id = 0) {
// change URL for Amazon bucket
}
```

but this is not working as expected as I am getting `$post_id` as `0`. How to do it in a proper way?

Comment: Have you seen [this answer](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/16817/73)?

Answer (score 1):

Hook wp_get_attachment_link for this purpose. Here is an example of how to do it -

```
function attachment_link_filter( $content, $post_id, $size, $permalink ) {
 
    // Only do this if we're getting the file URL
    if (! $permalink) {
        // This returns an array of (url, width, height)
        $image = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $post_id, 'large' );
        $new_content = preg_replace('/href=\'(.*?)\'/', 'href=\'' . $image[0] . '\'', $content );
        return $new_content;
    } else {
        return $content;
    }
}
 
add_filter('wp_get_attachment_link', 'attachment_link_filter', 10, 4);
```

Comment: i tried this but it snot working, as i am not able to see if this function is getting called even.