# How do I rewrite attachment urls when permalink structure contains %category%?

Tags: permalinks, url-rewriting, attachments

I'm trying to change the permalinks to my attachments in the same way as [this question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/2133/changing-attachment-urls), and the given solution works great except for one problem: if the permalinks settings on my site contain %category%, the solution doesn't work at all and I get a "This page isn't redirecting properly" error. The only way I can get this solution to work properly is by using the provided "Day and Name", "Month and Name", and "Numeric" permalink settings.

What do I add to the solution so that still use %category% in my custom permalink settings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like what I want is something that WordPress's internal permalink code isn't prepared to deal with. After reading [this writeup by Otto](http://ottopress.com/2010/category-in-permalinks-considered-harmful/), I've come to understand that having my permalinks start with %category% could create a performance issue down the road and I would have to create a function that further alters the WordPress permalink rules in order to get the attachment permalinks working with %category%.

As a result, I've decided to start all my posts with the year. This allows me to use the solution found [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/2133/changing-attachment-urls) for attachment permalinks, and I'll avoid performance headaches in the future.